# storing search term in database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to store the search keyword to my database. In my search term I am making use of the YouTube API and searching YouTube videos.

```
<input spellcheck="false" value="" id="searchBox" class="statusPlaying"><span id="searchTermKeyword">amisha patel</span>
```

For storing search terms in the database I have done this, but its not working. Can anyone give any idea how I can store the search terms without refreshing the page?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="title" class="statusPlaying" id="searchBox" value="" spellcheck="false">
    <span id="searchTermKeyword"></span>
</form>
```

Here is my [live link](http://way2enjoy.com/try/k/ytitest1.php#amisha)|

Comment: Can you show your server-side code which receives the form post please

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: Are you saying that just submitting a form does'nt just magically store stuff in your database, or have you tried something at all?

Comment: @adeneo i know how to process the form to store the details in databas  but i am not getting how to fill the value field automatically after search has been performed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan server side code is just plain insert which inserts in mysql

Comment: @TimCroydon  i know how to process the form to store the details in databas but i am not getting how to fill the value field automatically after search has been performed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to send something to your server without reloading the whole page. Therefore you'll need to use AJAX. Suggest starting with the jQuery Ajax as it's simple and well tested: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Basically, without giving you all the detail, you'll need to:

- bind to some event to trigger the send (e.g. 'change' on your input element)
- serialise the form data (e.g. using `$.serialize()` http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)
- make a `$.ajax()` call

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to store data without refreshing the page use Ajax (with or without jQuery, it's up to you).

See examples here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

You can use:

```
$.ajax()
$.post()
$.get()
etc.
```